# Extra qualification C++

Tags: c++, class

my compiler is telling me that I have an extra qualification error on one of my member functions, but I'm not sure why.

```
class DigitalTime {
 public:
  void DigitalTime::intervalSince(const DigitalTime& prev, int interval) const;
};

void DigitalTime::intervalSince(const DigitalTime& prev, int interval) const {
  return;
}
```

When I compile it, it says that my function intervalSince is extra qualified. I hope you guys can help me fix this issue

```
main.cpp:3:21: error: extra qualification on member 'intervalSince'
  void DigitalTime::intervalSince(const DigitalTime& aPreviousTime,
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Just as a note, look how much simpler this question is to read once we take your code and remove all of the code that is not related to your error!

Answer (score 7):

When defining functions and variables inside the class definition, don't prefix them with the class name:

```
class DigitalTime {
public:
    void DigitalTime::intervalSince(const DigitalTime& previous, int interval);
};
```

Should be:

```
class DigitalTime {
public:
    void intervalSince(const DigitalTime& previous, int interval);
};
```

Comment: Interesting (to me :-) trivia. I've been porting some legacy code from ancient Solaris to g++ on  RHEL8. The Old Solaris compiler let this through without complaint !